# mod_rewrite and .htaccess: Can my RewriteRule substitution be a subfolder in DocumentRoot's parent folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Thanks for your help in advance.

Here's where I am and what I am trying to accomplish:

- I have static files in /home/username/code/project/static/
- My document root is /home/username/public_html/ (which is where my .htaccess file is).
- I'm trying to use the following in the .htaccess file (I have no access to httpd.conf):

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(static/.*)$ /home/username/code/project/static/ [L]
  ```

  but if I understand mod_rewrite's documentation correctly (see below), "/home/username/code/project/static/" will be treated either as a file-system path relative to my document root or as a URL path, not as an absolute file-system path as I intended.

I tried using "~/code/project/static/" and "../code/project/static/", but I got an internal server error when trying to visit my page (yes, I'm a bit of a noob).

So my question is: is there a way for the substitution of a rewrite rule used in a .htaccess context to be an absolute file-system path rather than a path relative to my DocumentRoot?

Here's the extract from the mod_rewrite documentation for reference (can be found in full here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> For example, if you specify a Substitution string of /www/file.html, then this will be treated as a URL-path unless a directory named www exists at the root or your file-system **(or, in the case of using rewrites in a .htaccess file, relative to your document root)**, in which case it will be treated as a file-system path.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be to create a symlink within public_html that points `static` to `/home/username/code/project/static/`. This requires the `FollowSymlnks` option as detailed in the [Options Directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) but may not be allowed within the full Apache configuration, which is out of your control.

A better approach would be to reverse the link - make public_html/static where you keep the real files and then make /home/username/code/project/static a symlink to public_html/static. This avoids any need for specific .htaccess rules. Since it seems that you want to make the files under that directory publicly-accessible anyways, it's also better security-wise since it keeps the publicly-accessible files all under the same directory structure and avoids potential security issues that arise from allowing symlinks to go from within the web root to other areas of the file system.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I couldn't use `Options +FollowSymLinks` but `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` is allowed. Here's the command I used to create the symbolic link (for other noobs like me): `$ ln -s /home/username/code/project/static /home/username/public_html/static`